# How to show all non-aggregate field values

Tags: t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm probably overlooking something simple, but I don't see it.
Supposed I have a table of participants and scores

```
[Name]   [Score]
Tom      12
Tom      14
Tom      20
Dick     14
Dick     17
Harry    23
```

and I want to show everybody who participated more than once, and all their scores. This means that in this example, I want to show all records except for the last one.
The first part would be easy - just group by name and add `having count([Score])>1`. But then how to display all the scores too?

I tried experimenting with not grouping and adding `count([Score]) over (partition by [Name])`, but that's not a valid expression to filter by. You can't do `(count([Score]) over (partition by [Name]))>1`.

So in the end I went with

```sql
SELECT * from [Table]
where [Name] in (
     SELECT [Name] from [Table]
     GROUP by [Name]
     HAVING count([Score])>1
)
```

and this works, but I wonder if there's a better way.
(The real query is longer and involves more joined tables, which all have to be repeated inside the inner select, so this feels... dirty. Violating the DRY principle.)
So is this the best I can do? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is other way is to use of `exists` instead of `in`

```
select * 
from table t
where exists (
    select 1 from table 
    where name = t.name
    group by name
    having count(1) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You nailed it pretty much. There is no escape from calculating the repeated names in a subquery and then using their result to filter the original table. You can use `IN` or `EXISTS`, although they are slightly different (when using `IN`, if at least one result is `NULL` then it will never match!). I'd rather use `EXIST` instead.

```
SELECT 
    T1.* 
from 
    [Table] T1
where
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'the name appears at least twice with not null score'
        FROM
            [table] T2
        WHERE
            T1.name = T2.name -- NULL names won't match here!
        GROUP BY
            T2.name
        HAVING
            COUNT(score) > 1)
```

Comment: OK... Thanks for the warning about NULL results. But if I change my query to use EXISTS instead, the execution time is twice as long as with IN. (As I said, the actual query is more complicated and involves more tables.) Is there a solution to that? My main table doesn't have nullable fields and all the joins are inner joins, so there won't be any NULL results, and I'd rather use the fastest version in production.

Comment: You can try doing the windowed count in a CTE or subquery and filtering the result afterwards, it might be faster than repeating your big query again just to group by name.